# How to access nested variable using debug module in Ansible

Tags: python, variables, debugging, ansible

I use this task to access **files**:

```
- name: Find logs files
  find:
    paths: /var/log/
    patterns: "*.log"
    recurse: yes
    register: list_matched

- debug:
    var: list_matched.files
```

Output is:

```
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "changed": false,
    "examined": 17,
    "files": [
        {
            "atime": 1576496687.5594354,
            "ctime": 1576496687.5594354,
            "dev": 2049,
            "gid": 0,
            "gr_name": "root",
            "inode": 922589,
            "isblk": false,
            "ischr": false,
            "isdir": false,
            "isfifo": false,
            "isgid": false,
            "islnk": false,
            "isreg": true,
            "issock": false,
            "isuid": false,
            "mode": "",
            "mtime": ,
            "nlink": 1,
            "path": "/var/log/mikrotik/mikrotik.log",
            "pw_name": "root",
            "rgrp": true,
            "roth": true,
            "rusr": true,
            "size": 0,
            "uid": 0,
            "wgrp": false,
            "woth": false,
            "wusr": true,
            "xgrp": false,
            "xoth": false,
            "xusr": false
        },
```

How can I get **path** parameter? I was trying also something like this:

```
- debug:
    var: list_matched.files.path
```

But an error occured:

```
ok: [127.0.0.1] => {
    "files_matched.path": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!: 'dict object' has no attribute 'path'"
```

I want to capture **path** parameter, but no idea how. It was also hard to find some information about this nested debugging case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an open bracket "[" after "files:" so  you need to go that position on the array before going to path.

Try:

```
var: list_matched.files[0].path
```

Or:

```
var: list_matched.files[0]["path"]
```

To answer the comment, "how should I use it when I get more paths?" try getting the length of the array of "list_matched.files" and looping through it like this:

```
many_paths = []
for i in range(len(list_matched.files)):
    print(list_matched.files[i].path)
    many_paths.append(list_matched.files[i].path)

print(many_paths)
```

Maybe you want to save them into an array of paths.

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly for one path, but how should I use it when I get more paths?

Comment: I updated the answer with a loop to print out the other paths and save them to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Find returns a `dict` of values, so you must iterate over the list.

```
- name: Show file paths
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item.path }}"
  with_items: "{{ list_matched.files }}"
```